# MATLAB: how to solve this constrained optimization in MatLab

Tags: matlab, optimization, constraint-programming, correspondence

I want to do the following constrained optimization problem in MatLab:

Suppose we want to maximize an objective function f(x,t) = x - t, s.t. x is in [-1/t, 1/t]. X is our choice variable and t is a given parameter. Suppose X is in the real and T is in the Real++.

It's obvious, since f(.) is crescent in x and t>0, that, for a given t, the solution will be x*(t)=1/t. But how can I obtain this in Matlab? So that i can plot t vs x*(t).

I started programming this year, then I am sorry if the code I am looking for is too easy. I tried to do it by myself, but I could'nt.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Similar problems can be handled in different ways. If you want to use the official Matlab toolbox, you can have a look at: https://www.mathworks.com/products/optimization.html. This is probably the easiest solution.

Alternatively, you can model yourself the problem and the constraints, using optimization functions as csminwel.m (http://sims.princeton.edu/yftp/optimize/). It is more complicated from a programming perspective, since it generally requires that you convert your parameters of interest so that their support is unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

If you have optimization toolbox, you can solve constrained optimization problem by using `fmincon` function. Please click [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html).

Alternatively you can use the external library [Yalmip](https://yalmip.github.io/?n=Tutorials.Tutorials).

Comment: You don't have to use **fmincon**, since you can solve the problem using **linprog**. You should the following: f = [1; -1], Aeq = [0, 1], beq = t, defining the upper and the lower bounds accordingly. Have a look at https://uk.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/linprog.html for further clarifications.